# angular filter to convert a number to billions with two decimal points

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and I am learning how to create filters in angular. Can anybody please suggest is there a filter to convert a given number to billions with two decimal places?

Comment: Divide your number by a billion and use [the `currency` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your question but does something like this look right?

```
angular.module('billionsFilter', []).filter('toBillions', function() {
  return function(number, digits) {
    digits = angular.isNumber(digits) ? digits : 2; 
    return (number * 1000000000).toFixed(digits);
  };
});
```

Called like this:

```
{{49|toBillions}}  => "49000000000.00"
```

Or with a different number of digits:

```
{{49|toBillions:0}}  => "49000000000"
{{49|toBillions:4}}  => "49000000000.0000"
```